# Is it good practice to keep comments on HTML(ASPX) pages?

Tags: html, comments

I am developing web applications on asp.net with c#, is it good practice to keep comments on HTML(.aspx) pages?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Yes Sure. Comments Help To Identify Specific Function and Code.In Future also It become Easy if We Need To Make Changes in Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using comments always make good sense to a programmer. 
Not only the developers, others who view the code can also understands the functionality of that particular function.
Adding comments is always like sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's uselessness. You can insert comments text, autor, date etc. to MySQL and then print it by SELECT query